# Parsing JSON w/ Swiftly JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to pull a json object from the iTunes API and parse it using Swiftly JSON. I'm trying to output the artist name to console just to test that it's working, but I can't for the life of me get a result.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=909253")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
        let json = JSON(data)

        let name = json["results"][0]["artistName"].stringValue

       println ("Artist: \(name)")
    }

    task.resume()
```

Comment: Look at this library. It has some great helper functions to work with json. https://github.com/3pehrbehroozi/SwiftBooster/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let json = JSON(data:data)
```